# Execute Js Script in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I would like to ask why when I execute this, it does not return a value into numOfPeople . Thanks a lot.

```
People.prototype.deleteAllPeople = function(){
        var numOfPeople = this.getNumOfPeole();
        for (var i = 0; i < numOfPeople; i++) {
            try{
                this.click(this.By.xpath(this.getPeopleByOrder(i) + this.classContains('padding')
                + this.xPathContainText("Delete")));
            }catch(error){
                this.log("Cannot delete people " + i);
            }
        }
    };

    People.prototype.getNumOfPeole= function(){
        return this.driver.executeScript(
            "return jQuery(function($) { "
                + 'return $("div.single-pane").length;'
                + " }); "
        );
    };
```

Comment: which programming language you use to write Selenium tests?

Comment: Javascript, nodejs. Thanks for your help.